# Display Paginated column index in reverse order

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem during the display of paginated data. Default the program will display 5 rows per page and during the column index it is displaying the row no starting from 1, and then on the second page the row no will start from 6.

```
idx: 1 | name: John
idx: 2 | name: Doe
idx: 3 | name: John
idx: 4 | name: Doe
idx: 5 | name: John
```

**page = 2:**

```
idx: 6 | name: Tim
idx: 7 | name: John
idx: 8 | name: Doe
idx: 9 | name: John
idx: 10 | name: Doe
```

**Code:**

```
const names = [
    "John",
    "Doe",
    "John",
    "Doe",
    "John",
    "Tim",
    "John",
    "Doe",
    "John",
    "Doe",
];

let page = 1;
let limit = 5;
let totalCount = names.length || 0;

function pagination(array, page, limit) {
    return array.slice((page - 1) * limit, page * limit);
}

const newArray = pagination(names, page, limit);

newArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    const idx = (page - 1) * limit + (index + 1);
    console.log("idx:", idx, "|", "name:", item);
});
```

When I change page no to 2, then it will display starting row no 6 on the second page.

But the problem is I want to display the row indexing in reverse order something like this:
the first row should display the index as 10, and on the second page, the index starts from 5. How can I achieve this and what is the formula for this?

```
idx: 10 | name: John
idx: 9 | name: Doe
idx: 8 | name: John
idx: 7 | name: Doe
idx: 6 | name: John
```

**page = 2:**

```
idx: 5 | name: Tim
idx: 4 | name: John
idx: 3 | name: Doe
idx: 2 | name: John
idx: 1 | name: Doe
```

Comment: You could simply reverse your `names` array ... And if you actually need to show that "index" value as well, then that would be `totalCount+1-idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change only on idx varible calculation. hope it's useful for you.

```js
const names = [
  "John",
  "Doe",
  "John",
  "Doe",
  "John",
  "Tim",
  "John",
  "Doe",
  "John",
  "Doe",
];

let page = 1;
let limit = 5;
let totalCount = names.length || 0;

function pagination(array, page, limit) {
  return array.slice((page - 1) * limit, page * limit);
}

const newArray = pagination(names, page, limit);

newArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  const idx = totalCount - ((page - 1) * limit) - index;
  console.log("idx:", idx, "|", "name:", item);
});
```